# Implement Node Addon in Xcode

Tags: c++, node.js, xcode, node-gyp

Is there a way to run `node-gyp` on Xcode? So that I could add JavaScript, C++ files, third-party static libraries, and binding.gyp file in the same project, and run it with Node.js?

Or is writing separate files, putting them in the same directory, running js files on a terminal the only way to solve this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, we could implement `node-gyp` on Xcode.

Instead of commanding `$ node-gyp configure build`(or using `$ node-gyp rebuild`), what steps we should do are:

```
 $ node-gyp configure -- -f xcode
 $ node-gyp build
```

And we could also adjust some settings on Xcode itself, rather than editing `binding.gyp` alone.

Comment: This doesn't work in 2021 in Big Sur on Apple Silicon: `gyp: binding.gyp not found (cwd: /Users/hippietrail/example-node-addon) while trying to load binding.gyp`